# Method called when my UIViewController gets popped?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a UIViewController residing in a UINavController. The view controller which is playing audio through AVAudioPlayer. When it get's poped, it keeps playing audio, even though in the dealloc method I released the audioplayer.  I even tryed setting audioplayer to stop/pause before releasing it in dealloc, but it doesn't work.

So,

1. Why is it not calling dealloc when the UIViewController is popped?
2. What method should I use to stop the audioplayer right before/after the controller is popped.

EDIT: I don't think my view controller is being retained somehwere else. Here's my code when I allocate it and push it in nav controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *name = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    ToquesDetailVC *toqueDetail = [[ToquesDetailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToquesDetail"
                                                                audioPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mp4"]
                                                               imageNamed:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"jpg"]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:toqueDetail animated:YES];
    [toqueDetail release];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your view controller (the one that gets popped) isn't being retained somewhere else?

Comment: No, I am pretty sure. I updated my question the code. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nav controller does release the view controller but since you've retained it (with the initwithnibname call into toqueDetail), and it's autoreleased, it won't get dealloc'd until the run loop completes. You'll have to either not use the convenience intializer or explicitly clear the autorelease pool.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning point (2) did you try:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

on your view controller subclass to know when it 'disappears'?

Comment: It'll also disappear if you push another controller on top of it. If that's possible, then you don't know if it's popped or pushed down.

Comment: That's true, if you say push a modal view controller; but it should be possible to check after such an event to see if audio (in this question) should still be playing. I admit it's not an ideal hook, since you have several cases when the view disappears. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the audio player delegate, and if so, is that holding a reference to the VC? The code to the class that actually has the problem might help us solve this faster. o_O